# Why clipboardData doesn't have screenshots data

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

If I take a screenshot with my keyboard's 'Print screen' key, copy it and paste it into a plain `<div contenteditable />` element, the screenshot will just work and displayed there as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/2sf7benL/1/

However, if I add the `paste` event listener to the `<div contenteditable />` element, and paste screenshots into it, nothing is captured in the `clipboardData` object as shown here https://jsfiddle.net/kds265Lv/2/

**EDIT**
To add more context:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Press the 'Print Screen' key on your keyboard
2. Paste it in the demo below.
3. The screenshot will be displayed in the `<div />`.

```css
div { height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
```

That's the final result I desire. Now, instead of simply pasting it in the `contenteditable`, I listen to its `paste` event in order to access the screenshot in the `clipboardData` and finally render it using the `URL.createObjectURL` in the `contenteditable`:

```js
function handlePaste (e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;

  // Stop data actually being pasted into div
  e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

  // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    console.log(clipboardData)// this is always empty when i paste screenshots
    console.log(clipboardData.files[0]) // TADA!!!
    // Do whatever with pasteddata
}

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```css
div {height: 200px; width:200px; border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div id='editableDiv' contenteditable='true'></div>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: please show enough code in the question to reproduce the issue. You can even create a [runnable demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: pasting into the contenteditable directly (via your first method) doesn't seem to work either. at least not in Chrome/Windows 10, anyway. I ran it both in the snippet here, and in the JSFiddle, with no results. No console errors either, it just didn't paste anything (but I was able to paste the same screenshot into an email in Outlook, so the screenshot definitely worked). I was able to paste text into it, but not a screenshot. What configuration have you tested it with?

Comment: @ADyson thanks for digging into the matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow why am I so dumb... but to be fair Firefox and Chrome's consoles are misleading.. It's actually working but console.log `event` and `event.clipboardData` in chrome/FF gonna give you false negative results like empty arrays and `length: 0` :(

So you just gotta dig deeper like so:
`event.clipboardData.files[0]`

And you will see it!